# jQuery & PHP Don't Work Together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use jQuery to add some effects to a project I am currently working on. So far I have used PHP to reuse a header and footer file. As a test, I have tried to hide, then fade a logo in using jQuery. Here is the code I used to do this:

```
jQuery("#logo").hide(); 
jQuery("#logo").fadeIn();
```

However, this code doesn't have any effect at all.

Here is the PHP header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href = "img/favicon.png">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src = "js/myscript.js"></script>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "wrapper">

        <header>
            <div id = "logo"><img src = "img/logo.png"></div>
            <h1 id = "name">Nuri Amari</h1>

            <nav>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href = "index.php" class="<?php if ($section == 'About') { echo 'selected'; }?>">About</a></li>
                    <li class = "greyed-out">/</li>
                    <li><a href = "work.php" class="<?php if ($section == 'Work') { echo 'selected'; } ?>">Work</a></li>
                    <li class = "greyed-out">/</li>
                    <li><a href = "contact.php" class="<?php if ($section == 'Contact') { echo 'selected'; } ?>">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </nav>

        </header>
```

I include this header file into my index.php in the following code:

```
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>
```

I saw another post that said using PHP and jQuery together wasn't a bad idea. What am I doing wrong? I am a beginner to both languages so forgive me if my error is obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Apologies for my mistake, in previous posts I was told I posted too much code.

Comment: What you have posted has nothing to do with PHP. You also haven't posted the HTML containing `#logo`. How are we supposed to know what's wrong here?

Comment: You should show more HTML, where is your `#logo` for example

Comment: You're most likely trying to hide #logo before it loads. Just look at almost any jQuery example.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. Thanks, Alvaro. That fixed things. Again I am very new to jQuery in particular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language (meaning that it is run on the hosting server.) While jQuery is a javascript library run at the client side. Because of this they cant be in conflict of one another.

My quess is that you run your jQuery code before the webpage resources has finished loading.

Try adding your jQuery like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     //Your jQuery goes here eg: 
     $("#logo").hide(); 
     $("#logo").fadeIn();
 });
```

This tells jQuery to wait until the document is ready and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logo").hide(); 
    $("#logo").fadeIn();
});
```

BTW, Writing jQuery and writing $ is the same.